# How to use setGravity(Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK)

Tags: android, layout, gravity

I need to add a element into a LinearLayout aligned to the left and centered vertically. I think that it must be done with `VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK` but i dont know how to use.

This is the code i have at the moment:

```
pageLeftll.setGravity(Gravity.VERTICAL_GRAVITY_MASK);
```

I don't know how to continue and i can't find the way on google. Any help will be apreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
pageLeftll.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
```